# Zooming about point when using a Viewbox inside a ZoomableCanvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming

Thanks to Kael Rowan, you can easily create a zoomable canvas in `WPF`. **Sample project** can be downloaded at the bottom of [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/08/18/zoomableapplication3-when-not-to-applytransform.aspx).

Now, I need to modify this sample project to use its `Viewbox` feature. In `MainWindow.xaml` set the `Viewbox`, `Stretch` and `ApplyTransform` properties as follows:

```
<ZoomableCanvas ... Viewbox="0 0 400 400" Stretch="Fill" ApplyTransform="True" />
```

### The problem

With this feature enabled, the zooming using the mouse wheel does not zoom about the mouse position. Instead, it seems to zoom around (0,0). This piece of code (in the mouse wheel handler) works **without** `Viewbox`:

```
// Adjust the offset to make the point under the mouse stay still.
var position = (Vector)e.GetPosition(MyListBox);
MyCanvas.Offset = (Point)((Vector)(MyCanvas.Offset + position) * x - position);
```

How can I get it working **with** a `Viewbox`? This is driving me nuts! Math/WPF gurus out there, please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{ 
    var position = e.GetPosition(this.MyCanvas);

    var pre = this.MyCanvas.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(position);

    var x = Math.Pow(2, e.Delta / 3.0 / Mouse.MouseWheelDeltaForOneLine);
    MyCanvas.Scale *= x;

    var cur = this.MyCanvas.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(position);

    var offset = (cur - pre);

    this.MyCanvas.Offset += offset;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you try it? I cannot get it working. Maybe the `Viewbox` property should somehow be used in the mouse wheel handler?